# Aparece un signo raro en páginas de servidor �

Tags: php

Recién emigré mi página web a este servidor

Ahora aparece este signo � en los textos de mi páginas que están en una base de datos.

Mi programador no lo puede arregla.
Tengo la misma base de datos en otro servidor que no trae este problema.

Qué solución hay.

Comment: Incluye más detalles, servidor de partida, el nuevo, ¿donde aparece ese símbolo? Supongo que en acentos, eñes, etc... ¿en la Base de datos o en las páginas de la web? juego de caracteres de la BD en uno y otro servidor, tipo de BD, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Posiblemente tu base de datos y/o tus páginas estuvieran desarrolladas en una página de códigos local, como ISO-8859-xx o alguna propia de Windows. Los servidores modernos utilizan UTF-8.

Es un problema complejo porque esto se debería haber tenido en cuenta a la hora de mirar y exportar e importar todo correctamente.

En primer lugar tienes que averiguar con qué codificación está tu página y tu base de datos, después puedes probar a ajustar la configuración de ambas para concuerde, y ver si así funciona.

Por ejemplo en la cabecera de tu página web debería aparecer algo parecido a:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
```